# Plotting the acceptance curve, rejection and indecision in sign test and signed rank test

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have this code which generates 10 intervals for each value of M and calculates the center of each interval. Then I want to do the sign test and signed rank test for each center. After that i wanted to plot 3 curves for the sign test and 3 curves for the signed rank test. (the curves are the acceptance, rejection and indecision curves.all of them in the same plot)

```
# Load required libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
# Function to perform the sign test for a single vector
perform_sign_test <- function(x, median_hypothesis, alpha = 0.05) {
  n_pos <- sum(x > median_hypothesis)
  n_neg <- sum(x < median_hypothesis)
  
  # Calculate the test statistic T (minimum of positive and negative counts)
  T <- min(n_pos, n_neg)
  
  # Calculate the p-value using binomial distribution
  p_value <- 2 * pbinom(T, n_pos + n_neg, 0.5)
  
  return(p_value)
}

# Function to perform the signed rank test for a single vector and calculate p-value
perform_signed_rank_test <- function(x, median_hypothesis, alpha = 0.05) {
  diffs <- x - median_hypothesis
  n_pos <- sum(diffs > 0)
  
  # Calculate the absolute differences and their ranks
  abs_diffs <- abs(diffs)
  ranks <- rank(abs_diffs)
  
  # Calculate the test statistic T (sum of the ranks of positive differences)
  T <- sum(ranks[diffs > 0])
  
  # Calculate the variance of the test statistic (under the null hypothesis of no difference)
  var_T <- (n_pos*(n_pos + 1)*(2 * n_pos + 1)) / 6
  
  # Calculate the Z value for alpha / 2 (two-tailed test)
  Z_alpha_over_2 <- qnorm(1 - alpha / 2)
  
  # Calculate the p-value
  p_value <- 2 * min(pnorm(-abs(T), mean = 0, sd = sqrt(var_T)), pnorm(abs(T), mean = 0, sd = sqrt(var_T), lower.tail = FALSE))
  
  return(p_value)
}



# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(124)

# Set the number of samples
n_samples <- 10

M_values <- seq(-1, 1, by = 0.10)
n <- length(M_values)

# Initialize vectors to store the results
sign_test_results <- numeric(length(M_values))
signed_rank_test_results <- numeric(length(M_values))

for (i in seq_along(M_values)) {
  M <- M_values[i]
  
  # Generate a sample of observations for this M-value
  sample <- rnorm(n_samples, mean = M, sd = 1)
  
  # Perform the sign test for this sample and store the result
  sign_test_results[i] <- perform_sign_test(sample, median_hypothesis = 0, alpha = 0.05)
  
  # Perform the signed rank test for this sample and store the result
  signed_rank_test_results[i] <- perform_signed_rank_test(sample, median_hypothesis = 0, alpha = 0.05)
}

# Create a data frame to store the results
results_df <- data.frame(M = M_values,
                         sign_test_p_value = sign_test_results,
                         signed_rank_test_p_value = signed_rank_test_results)

# Add the decision category to the dataframe for each test
results_df$sign_test_decision <- ifelse(results_df$sign_test_p_value <= 0.05, "Rejection", 
                                        ifelse(results_df$sign_test_p_value >= 0.05, "Acceptance", "Indecision"))
results_df$signed_rank_test_decision <- ifelse(results_df$signed_rank_test_p_value <= 0.05, "Rejection", 
                                               ifelse(results_df$signed_rank_test_p_value >= 0.05, "Acceptance", "Indecision"))

# Plot the results
ggplot(results_df, aes(x = M)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = sign_test_p_value, color = sign_test_decision, linetype = "Sign Test")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = signed_rank_test_p_value, color = signed_rank_test_decision, linetype = "Signed Rank Test")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Acceptance" = "green", "Rejection" = "red", "Indecision" = "blue")) +
  labs(x = "M values", y = "P value", color = "Decision", linetype = "Test") +
  theme_minimal()
```

What I obtained are really different decisions for each test, but they should coincide(almost in all cases) but they only coincide in n=1000 that gives p values of 0 . So, something is wrong right? The plot I want to achieve is something like this

[image]

and i am obtaining this, which is pretty far from the desired plot. I need some help understanding what is wrong with it.

[image]

Comment: Also the values of the p-values for the signed rank test are always much smaller than the sign test, so in the signed rank test the decision is always reject the hypothesis, which is weird